# Difference between terms and atomic formula

Tags: predicate-logic

What is the difference between terms and atomic formulae?
I get contradicting advice from everywhere. 
On one hand I have got written if $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are terms and if $F$ is a function symbol with arity $n$ then $F(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is a term.

Then on the other hand I have been told that if $F$ is a function symbol with arity $2$ and given $x$ and $y$ are variables, then $F(x,y)$ is an atomic formulae.

Are terms and atomic formulae the same of different?

Comment: This probably depends on whose system of logic you are using. In the ones I am most familiar with, a term is like a noun: an object or number, etc. A formula is a sentence: Sam touched the ball. In that formula, Sam and the ball are terms and F(A,B) = A touched B is a sentential formula.

Comment: I think this could be clarified if the definition of formula, predicate and term where written out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Warning: do not mix up *terms*, *variables*, *constants*, *functions* and *predicates*.

In First-Order Logic, **terms** function as names, and well-formed formulas (atomic or not) as statements. There is a neat **inductive definition of a term**:

1. A single occurrence of a variable is a term;
2. A single occurrence of a constant symbol is a term;
3. If $f$ is an $n$-ary function (meaning that it takes $n$ arguments), and $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_n$ are terms, then $ft_1t_2\ldots t_n$ is a term.

Now, the **direct definition of an atomic formula**:

- If $P$ is an $n$-ary predicate symbol and $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_n$ are terms, then $Pt_1t_2\ldots t_n$ is an atomic formula.

These two definitions look a bit similar (just a bit, though), so let me make it very clear:

- A **TERM** is an **ELEMENT OF THE LANGUAGE** (by its inductive definition, it can be as simple as a single occurrence of a constant or a variable, or arbitrarily complicated if it is formed with a function).
- An **ATOMIC FORMULA** is a **LOGICAL STATEMENT**, i.e. one to which you can assign a **TRUTH-VALUE**. From atomic formulae, you can build up, using logical connectives, any other formula.
- A **FUNCTION** takes $n$ terms and is evaluated as a **NEW TERM**.
- A **PREDICATE** takes $n$ terms and is evaluated as a **TRUTH VALUE**.

Comment: Thank you, I understand things much clearly. But what about F(x,y) then. It is still an atomic formula because it is a term and terms can be atomic formula because terms are the building blocks of formula?

Comment: If $F$ is a function and $x,y$ are terms, then $F(x,y)$ is a term. This notation (with the brackets) is not the standard notation in logic. It looks more like something you would write in maths. And in maths, a function $F(x,y)$, with $x,y$ some numbers, returns another number (a function of terms returns a new term).

Comment: Why is the equality symbol an atomic formula?

Comment: However, if $F$ is a 2-place predicate, say $F(x,y)$: "$x$ is greater than "y", and $x,y$ are terms, then $F(x,y)$ is an atomic formula, and will return a truth-value (true if indeed $x>y$, false otherwise).

Comment: Because the equality symbol is a 2-place predicate. It takes two terms, checks a property, and returns true/false. When you say $x=y$, you mean that "it is true that $x$ equals $y$". You wouldn't use $x=y$ as a number (read, a term).

Comment: you are really amazing at explaining logic stuff, have a look at my question "valuations and logic" please mate.

Comment: can't predicates have logical symbols? if yes, then what is the difference between atomic formula vs formula. Perhaps (recursively) defining a formula would be helpful :)